# Upload Image and stay on page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm bulding a website that allows users to upload a picture and then get the EXIF info shown in a user-friendly way.

I also want to make available an option for users to be able to share their picture online.

At the moment I already have the JavaScript for the image preview fully working, I select an Image on a Form and it appears on the website...

I also have the upload part of the code working as well (PHP). The image gets uploaded to a folder and the name and path of the respective image get uploaded to the MySQL database.

The thing is... I want the process to happen in this way:

1. User selects the picture - WORKING
2. The picture appears on display as a preview - WORKING
3. User presses the upload button (if he wishes to) - WORKING
4. The image gets uploaded to the defined folder and the name and path to the DB - WORKING
5. Website stays on the same page with the image preview still there... - TO BE DONE
6. A new text-area appears on the website with the image path inside (gotten from the database) so the user can share the image - TO BE DONE

----------------//-------------------

I've read some articles and topics on this and supposedly it needs to be done using JQuery in order to work in the way I defined above...

Could you guys clarify if that's true?

---------------//---------------

**UPDATE**

The solution @Dhanushka sasanka presented worked! I can now upload the picture to the folder and the info to the database and it stays on the page without refreshing!!

Comment: If you want to upload data to the server without leaving the current page, then yes, AJAX is the usual way to achieve that.

Comment: You are trying to tackle several issues in the same question. `The solution @Dhanushka sasanka presented worked!`. Accept his answer and ask a new question pertaining to the path.

Comment: @EternalHour I'm sorry for the mess. Gonna clean it up :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this You must use `JqueryForm Plugin` to do this because In the Form that your "upload" button it must be `type="submit"` therefore current page will be reload after pressing that "upload" button so you must use this plugin [JQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started)
Go through this one.from this you can uplaod your image without reloading page.

Answer (score 0):

`Sending data to server in background without refresh/reload/change the current page` can be done with javascript `AJAX Request`.

If you want to pass data to server and stay on the same page, Then Yes you need to use `AJAX` in Javascript.

But using `Jquery` is much easy to implement `Ajax request and callbacks`, So go with jQuery.